# MacOS Rstudio devtools loading fails

Tags: r, github, package, devtools

I need to install the package devtools in R on my mac. The R version is 3.2.3.
It gives an error saying

```
Warning in install.packages :
download had nonzero exit status
Warning in install.packages :
download of package ‘curl’ failed
```

Other posts addressing similar issues provide solutions to Linux (with the apt-get command, etc) but doesn't seem to have a Mac solution. Highly appreciate if someone with insight can offer some guide here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem pertains to the download, have a look [at this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300582/download-file-in-r-has-non-zero-exit-status). You can consider downloading the package first and installing a package from a local zip file.

```
install.packages("local_package_file", repos = NULL)
```

or more specifically:

```
install.packages("devtools.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

as shown [on the devtools @ GitHub](https://github.com/hadley/devtools).

---

*You didn't mentioned, but I understand that you have the [**Xcode**](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) installed as well. Alternatively, it could be informative to check if your R compiler has no problems with connecting to the Internet, you can use the code: **`is.character(getURL("www.google.com"))`**.*

Comment: Thanks @Konrad!  I will try your suggestion and see if it fixes the issue